# Wrong colors antialiasing with Pygame on OS X

Tags: macos, drawing, pygame, antialiasing

I'm using Pygame on a Macbook Pro (non-retina) running OS X.  When I try to create an antialiased line or circle, it seems to be coming out as the wrong color.  Here's an example:

```
import sys, pygame, random, math
import pygame.gfxdraw

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)


pygame.init()

size = width, height = 800, 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

# make the background
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
#background.fill(black)
background.fill(white)

while 1:
    # handle single events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE: sys.exit()

    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

    pygame.draw.line(screen, green, [0, 0], [50,30], 1)
    pygame.draw.aaline(screen, green, [0, 50],[50, 80], True)

    pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, [100, 100], 10)
    pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(screen, 100, 130, 10, black)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Which leads to:

[image: color example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haven't been able to find the cause for this despite searching through the pygame source code.

I did manage to come up with a workaround though. Two actually.

There seems to be a bug in the `pygame.gfxdraw` module that causes colors to be messed up in OS X when the value for blue is 0. If you change your `black` to (0,0,1), the circle will already look much better, but still have a slight blueish tinge.  Change it to (0,0,2) and it will appear pretty much completely black. Makes little sense to me but it works.

**Edit:** That's for background colors that don't contain any blue. It appears that on background RGBs containing >0 blue, the circle needs at least that amount of blue to prevent the bug. For example, to get a black aacircle on a (50,50,50) background, the closest I was able to get was by using (0,0,50) for the circle. Any lower amount of blue will result in bright blue artifacts.

Adding blue doesn't help for fixing `pygame.draw.aaline`'s behavior though. This must be a separate bug. However, `pygame.gfxdraw.line` is also anti-aliased. Use that method instead, change `green` to (0,255,1) and the cyan line will now be green.

[image]