# pygame aaline color displays incorrectly on mac

Tags: macos, colors, pygame

I am trying to draw a antialiased line in pygame with pygame.draw.aaline.

Here is my code:

```
# shows color bug with aaline

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((100, 100))
pygame.display.set_caption("aaline color wrong bug")
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))  # black background

L1_COLOR = (255, 255, 255)  # white
L2_COLOR = (  0,   0, 255)  # blue

for y in range(10):  # draw 10 lines next to each other
    pygame.draw.aaline(screen, L1_COLOR, (25, 30 + y), (75, 30 + y), True)
    pygame.draw.aaline(screen, L2_COLOR, (25, 60 + y), (75, 60 + y), True)

# Problem:  white shows as yellow, and blue shows as black


pygame.display.update()

done = False
while not done:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if e.type == KEYDOWN:
            if e.key in (K_ESCAPE, K_SYSREQ):
                done = True
```

I draw a white line 10 times to create a fat line and the same for a blue line. But when run the white line is yellow and the blue line is black on a black background.

This problem does not happen on linux, but it does on mac. Using Python 3.6 current pygame on mac running 10.13.5

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Check out if this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25775957/6220679) works. I think there was another question about the same problem, but I can't find it anymore and also don't remember if they could figure out a real solution to this problem.